# Upload gravatar in WP profile?

Tags: users, avatar, profiles, gravatar

I'm interested in the theory of a user being able to register/upload a gravatar directly in their user account within a hosted WP system.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to connect your sites sign-up with Gravatar then you simply can't, since Gravatar don't have a sing-up api you can use.

But if you are just looking to let your users upload there own photos the either Simple Local Avatars Plugin that Chip suggested or one I've used a lot before is [**User Photo**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-photo/) will do the job just fine.

But the better part of User Photo plugin is that it has an overwrite function  `get_avatar` which will get the user photo if exists or the gravatar if not.

Comment: Simple Local Avatars also works by filtering `get_avatar()`.

Comment: "you simply can't, since Gravatar don't have a sing-up api you can use"

Ah, I suppose that answers that for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Simple Local Avatars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) Plugin. It works exactly as advertised!

Comment: Yes, the SLA plugin is useful, but they won't be globally recognized, for third party plugins that integrate with WP and make use of gravatar.

Comment: They don't need to be *globally* recognized. They only need to be recognized by `get_avatar()` within WordPress - which this Plugin does.

Comment: Thanks Chip. I'm using the Disqus commenting system with a site that allows users to register advanced profiles. I'd like them to be able to upload their gravatar when filling in the other profile fields. Using SLA to upload an avatar means that when they comment using Disqus, the image will not show the SLA avatar, when it would normally show a gravatar. This is why I was interested in it being globally recognized. 

But I'm still working this theory out and how to best approach it.

Comment: Disqus has user profiles, and allows for complete template customization. Why not just use the avatars available through Disqus profiles?

Comment: It's a community driven website. So I'm trying to figure out the best approach to have their profile pic show on their profile and within their Disqus comments.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Jaquith a WP core developer wrote a plugin called [Gravatar Signup](http://txfx.net/wordpress-plugins/gravatar-signup/) which checks if the user has a Gravatar when the leave comments (and maybe when the first signup) and if not shows a link to the gravatar site. They would still need to sign up at Gravatar.com but this may be a simple fix to your problem.

Personally I try to stay away from plugins that allow users to upload their own author pics but that's just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Gravatar Box](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravatar-box/) which I wrote. It's handy for a comments form, to increase Gravatar awareness.