# Replace Gravatar with UserPhoto in All Users Coulmn view

Tags: users

I am using the UserPhoto plugin which allows users to upload a photo which can be used in many ways. (It's awesome) But I would also like when the admins look at the list of users the column displays this users photo instead of the Gravatar. Is there a hook?

I'm a little closer...

```
function change_user_avatar_col( $column ) {
    $column['avatar'] = 'avatar';

    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'change_user_avatar_col' );

function change_user_avatar( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'avatar' :
            return userphoto_thumbnail($user);
            break;

        default:
    }
    return $return;
} 
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'change_user_avatar', 10, 3 );
```

I am getting the images but they they are not in the column, plus I really want to replace the current gravatars and this is creating an additional column. I tried changing out the "avatar" to "Username" for the column but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but much probably this works:

Instead of trying to add/change the columns, change the `get_avatar` behavior.

For one, it is a pluggable function, so it can be overridden. And second, there are many Questions in this Stack on how to modify/customize the avatars.

Check this two:

- [Upload gravatar in WP profile?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/15153/12615)
- [Removing Gravatar.com support for WordPress and Simple Local Avatars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/17413/12615)

In the first one, Bainternet states:

> But the better part of User Photo plugin is that it has an overwrite function get_avatar which will get the user photo if exists or the gravatar if not.

Answer (score -2):

ok i solved this problem through hacking around

in the 
wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php

i eddited on line 285, the: case 'username' as followed

```
                  case 'username':                      
                    $user = get_userdata( $user_object->ID, 32);  
                    if (userphoto_exists($user)){ // set the userphoto picture as avatar > must be .jpg
                        $theImageUrl = "http://YOUR_WEBSITE/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/$user->ID.jpg";
                        $r .= "<td $attributes> <img src='$theImageUrl' width='32' height='32'/> $edit</td>";
                    }
                    else // if there is no user photo, set default avatar
                    {
                        $avatar = get_avatar($user->ID, 32);
                        $r .= "<td $attributes>$avatar $edit</td>";
                    } 
                    break;
```

note: user_photo pictures must be in .jpg.

my help-source for this was user > dikkevandale on > http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-user-photo-how-do-i-return-just-the-image-url

thx!
dimi

Comment: Dimi you used "hacking around" and I would consider this a hack. I was hoping to find a hook as to not touch the core. Thanks though.

Comment: Hacking the core is not considered a good answer in this Stack. Also, you are hardcoding the [`wp_upload_dir`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir).